# How to know why did I come to earth and how to retire from it?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, rebirth

How to know:

- Why did I come to earth and how to retire from it?
- Can some person remember the reason of his existence by doing Japa or meditation?

The "Who am I?" quest is taking too much depth but actually how to end it?

Comment: @sv. May be OP is not interested in knowing previous births.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Could be, he probably needs to edit it to make it unique.

Comment: "Who am I" is the most important question in spiritually and I think attaining the absolute truth is the answer for everything! (Mundaka Upanishad 1-3)